# How do I prevent HttpClient TaskCancelled Exception that happens 1 in around 1000 requests?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dotnet-httpclient

I've got this issue where when a form is submitted from our client facing application to the API occasionally it hangs. The API feeds quite a few things to our application and none of the other requests ever hang. It only seems to happen when forms are being submitted. These forms typically have small files attached (we have a 25Mb limit set, most of the time they're in the Kb). It only seems to happen with certain users with slower connection speeds. Here is the original implementation I inherited.

```
protected string ExecuteSecuredEndpoint(HttpMethod httpMethod, string endpointUrl, string accessToken, object body = null)
{ 
   var request = new HttpRequestMessage(httpMethod, $"{_baseUrl}{endpointUrl}");
   request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

   if (body != null)
      request.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");                      

  var response = Startup.HttpClient.SendAsync(request).Result;

  if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode == false) throw new HttpRequestException($"{response.ReasonPhrase} - {response.RequestMessage}");

  return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
```

This version failed with `AggregateException`. This makes sense because the original coder was running Async tasks Sync. So originally I though it maybe a dead lock situation created by using .Result . Since then I wrote this

```
protected async Task<string> ExecuteSecuredEndpointAsync(HttpMethod httpMethod, string endpointUrl, string accessToken, object body = null)
{
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(httpMethod, $"{_baseUrl}{endpointUrl}");

            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

            if (body != null)
                request.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");                       

            var response = await Startup.HttpClient.SendAsync(request);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode == false)
                throw new HttpRequestException($"{response.ReasonPhrase} - {response.RequestMessage}");

            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

The specific line it hangs on is `var response = await Startup.HttpClient.SendAsync(request);`. I only use the Async version to submit forms (very few forms are submitted from this application). However the same issue still happens only with `TaskCancelled` instead. Its not with all or even most requests. However I can't seem to recreate the issue either locally, on test servers, or production. Finally if I pass a cancellation token in with say a 30 second timeout, its ignored and still only times out at around 2-3 mins. Our apps are published in App (customer facing and API) Services within Azure. Any help would be appreciated. Let me know if you all need anymore info.

**Edit 1**: Here is the full stack trace from Application Insights

```
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException:
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at *Redacted*.Portal.Presentation.Customer.Api.Endpoints.BaseEndpoint+<ExecuteSecuredEndpointAsync>d__3.MoveNext (*Redacted*.Portal.Presentation.Customer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null*Redacted*.Portal.Presentation.Customer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: Path\Redacted\\Agent\_work\1\s\*Redacted*.Portal.Presentation.Customer\Api\Endpoints\BaseEndpoint.cs*Redacted*.Portal.Presentation.Customer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 55)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at *Redacted*.Portal.Presentation.Customer.Api.Endpoints.Company+<AddSupplierAsync>d__9.MoveNext (*Redacted*.Portal.Presentation.Customer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null*Redacted*.Portal.Presentation.Customer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: Path\Redacted\\Agent\_work\1\s\*Redacted*.Portal.Presentation.Customer\Api\Endpoints\Company.cs*Redacted*.Portal.Presentation.Customer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 78)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at *Redacted*.Portal.Presentation.Customer.Controllers.SupplierController+<Submit>d__3.MoveNext (*Redacted*.Portal.Presentation.Customer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null*Redacted*.Portal.Presentation.Customer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: Path\Redacted\\Agent\_work\1\s\*Redacted*.Portal.Presentation.Customer\Controllers\SupplierController.cs*Redacted*.Portal.Presentation.Customer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 58)
```

**Edit 2:** This application is targeting .Net Framework (4.7)

Comment: I'm guessing this is a `TaskCancelledException` that's caused by an interrupted HTTP request (e.g. a mobile phone user with a poor signal). **You can't prevent those** - in fact there's nothing you can do besides handle them gracefully.

Comment: @Dai So its happening server side and the request never leaves the server (I built the API as well and confirm the request never makes it). From some data collection I also can confirm they are not on a mobile device. They are typically in foreign countries though.

Comment: We can't know for certain **until and unless you post the full exception details** (including full `StackTrace` of all `InnerExceptions` in the graph), otherwise it's just guesswork. There's a 1,001+ reasons why a `TaskCancelledException` can be thrown.

Comment: @Dai Okay, I posted the stack trace as well. Hopefully this will help.

Comment: Is there anything in the `$exception.InnerException`? I must say, my nose smells someone hogging the ThreadPool somewhere, but maybe not

Comment: @Charlieface The stack-trace you posted is incomplete. Do you have any access to the full stack trace? Is there anything in your `SupplierController.Submit` action that hints at a cause?

Comment: @Charlieface No there is nothing in InnerException. Unfortunately this all of the Stack Trace I can get. The error isn't showing up in Dev. I'm doing some load testing now to try and reproduce.

Comment: @Hans Be aware that `AggregateException` has a different property: `InnerExceptions`, it doesn't use `InnerException`.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the call stack:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException:
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at *Redacted*.Portal.Presentation.Customer.Api.Endpoints.BaseEndpoint+<ExecuteSecuredEndpointAsync>d__3.MoveNext (*Redacted*.Portal.Presentation.Customer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null*Redacted*.Portal.Presentation.Customer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: Path\Redacted\\Agent\_work\1\s\*Redacted*.Portal.Presentation.Customer\Api\Endpoints\BaseEndpoint.cs*Redacted*.Portal.Presentation.Customer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 55)
```

The top first-party entry is `*Redacted*.Portal.Presentation.Customer.Api.Endpoints.BaseEndpoint+<ExecuteSecuredEndpointAsync>d__3.MoveNext`, which means the exception is thrown by an `await` in `ExecuteSecuredEndpointAsync`. (As a side note, check out [Ben.Demystifier](https://github.com/benaadams/Ben.Demystifier), which can extract more information from your exception stacks)

The only `await`s in `ExecuteSecuredEndpointAsync` have to do with `HttpClient`, and neither of them are passing in `CancellationToken`s. However, on .NET Core, `SendAsync` [can throw a `TaskCanceledException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.sendasync?view=net-5.0#System_Net_Http_HttpClient_SendAsync_System_Net_Http_HttpRequestMessage_) if there is a `Timeout`, and there is a [default `Timeout` of 100 seconds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout?view=net-5.0), a value that is nicely close to the "2-3 mins" observed time. (A very busy thread pool can cause an additional delay here)

So, the first thing to check is why the API is slow. Is this "proxy" co-located with the API in the same region? Is the API slow to read the request bodies for some reason? Perhaps its request queue is regularly full and just needs to scale out?

For a quick fix, I'd consider increasing the `Timeout` value.

Comment: So this is actually .Net Framework (4.7). Before, I would pass a cancellation token in with a say 30 second timeout on it. The request would still timeout at the default time. The request is never received by the API. As far as I can tell the the request hangs server side.